# DataTemplate inserting UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am creating `DataTemplate` for `MyObject`. `MyObject` contains , for example, `StackPanel` named `public StackPanel MyStackPanel`. How I can insert `MyStackPanel` into MyObject's DataTemplate?

Comment: Hmm, DataTemplates are usually intended for the consumer of your control to use.  Are you trying to create a sort of... default template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but I don't see why you'd want to.

In this example I use "Customer" as the object type and contain within it a Button (but it could just as easily be a StackPanel).

```
public class Customer : DependencyObject
{
    public Customer()
    {
        MyButton = new Button();
        MyButton.Content = "I'm a button!";
    }

    #region MyButton

    public Button MyButton
    {
        get { return (Button)GetValue(MyButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyButton", typeof(Button), typeof(Customer));

    #endregion

}
```

I'm not sure if you could do this without making your object a DependencyObject and defining the nested control as a dependency property. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged may work as an alternative (if your object can't inherit from DependencyObject), but I haven't tested that.

The MainWindow with the template:

```
<Window x:Class="TemplateTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TemplateTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyButton}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="CustomersList" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, I use a ContentPresenter to bind the button coming from the object.

You can then test it with this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                var myCustomer1 = new Customer();
                var myCustomer2 = new Customer();

                var customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
                customers.Add(myCustomer1);
                customers.Add(myCustomer2);

                CustomersList.ItemsSource = customers;
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do something like that, templates are building plans which are executed, they do not contain specific instances or references to specific instances.